# Steps in attaching a prepopulated sqlite database for android application

Tags: database, android-studio, android-assets

I want to build an android application which requires use of **predefined** **database **..which can be queried.can anyone please help ??!!

Comment: Building is good, now you are collecting the material. We can help, but what kind of schema shall be inside the database and what data loaded because those who query , often like an answer ... Do you have problems in creating tables, in constructing a database file or what. Please add to the question any those details and ideally what you tried already. Thanks.

Comment: My application basically do not generate any data

Comment: I have manually inserted datas into tables in sqlite manager...that's some dates and the events...my android layout let's to put a date and submit and it queries database and let's you know about the event...

Comment: But then it needs data, from this database, right? Please add details to the question what kind of data etc. is needed. Ah ok, so is the question how to actually "put" the file on the android device?

Comment: What kind of data?? Umm data as in all the dates in date colum table of a month which is in a year table....I have already stored those data's in my sqlite manger...I just need to use them in my application queries and retrieve data's from it..